# android xml parser use saxparser

Tags: android, xml

this is xml
[image]

this is imgclass

```
    public class empclass {
private String name;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

}

this is SAXhandler to get img
[image]

it will get all img. I just want get jame_1,jame_2,jame_3.how to to that.
sorry for my bad English. please help me

Comment: can any body help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get the tags based on the name attribute.

You can use `attributes.getValue` function .

Look at [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/sax/get-element-attributes-in-sax-xml-parsing/) example code.

Comment: @abcd1234 : look at the link I posted in my asnwer.

Comment: @abcd1234: If this solved your problem, you should accept the answer.